# How to simulate click based on x y position of pointer in jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

There are some point in canvas which triggers on click. I want to simulate that.

Comment: hello Aman RAJ, welcome to StackOverflow. We all need some code from you, otherwise question may be closed as "too broad". Provide a code that handles this click, also please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete code under test.